# Why is my hard drive listed under /media rather than /mnt

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am on Ubuntu.

The path to my 2nd hard drive is:

```
/media/bernie/8a080114-f436-421b-8860-b3bcc48ff193
```

Why isn't it under:

```
 /mnt/bernie
```

?

And what does the long folder name mean?

Answer (score 6):

That's just how Ubuntu automatically mounts disks these days. Behind the scenes it uses [udisks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/). `/media` is the standard mounting location for removable media. `/mnt`, for historic purposes, is reserved for manually mounting a partition temporarily, although obviously you can mount whatever you want there including permanent drives listed in the fstab. This information can be found [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#MEDIAMOUNTPOINT).

The long folder name is the UUID of the mounted partition. This is so that the system can automatically mount drives in a uniquely identifiable way which prevents the system from trying to mount two drives to the same folder, while also allowing the disk to be identified by the number instead of generic labels like 1, 2, 3, etc.